# what does "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATABASE_CHANGED" mean

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Saw this error a few times today in Chrome's developer tools, and trying to figure out what it means / what we can do to avoid it.

"Failed to load resource: net:: ERR_CERT_DATABASE_CHANGED"

This was causing some image urls to fail to load in our testing.  Fwiw I just checked the cert for the site in question, and it was issued over a year ago and is valid until the end of 2016, so it doesn't look like any changed serverside.

Google search turns up pretty much nothing for this error message, so hoping Stack Overflow will have more answers.

Answer (score 4):

So the best I've been able to discover is this: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/spdy/spdy_session_pool.cc and a few related tickets in Chromium about this code.  It would appear that when the system cert database changes - in my case, potentially just a crappy puppet policy double checking that only trusted certs are in our store - Chrome reacts by closing down all existing connections and returning network errors to any outstanding request.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
You may have Kaspersky Antivirus installed.
The Kaspersky software is manipulating the system keychain frequently (sometimes many times a second), which is causing Chrome to flush connections, because the system trust store has changed.

You can try it:

1. Remove Kaspersky;
2. disable Kaspersky web traffic interception

I also found a page with a description of the bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=925779#c29.

Comment: thanks for the advice.  this was on a work computer for me though... so disabling antivirus (not kapersky, fwiw) is not really reasonable to solve what I've only seen as a transient but recurring issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my iMac - Chrome, Tried several things but nothing worked, Only thing that worked for me is by deleting the expired certifications from the key chain (Key Chain -> View -> Show expired certificates -> Select system and sort by the expire date and you will see the expired certificates with dates and red check mark on the icon image of the certificate)